# How long does an ether transaction take until verification (and where do I get this data?)

Tags: timestamp

I am wondering if data is stored in the ETH blockchain on the time the transaction got send to the mempool such that I can deduce the time until it got included in a public afterwards (not to be confused with the average time until a new block is mined as not every transaction gets included in the subsequent block directly).

I find related data for BTC but not for ETH...any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Transaction is stored in blockchain once it mined and included into block.  Before this, transaction is stored by nodes outside blockchain (in memory or on disk).

Even after transaction was stored in blockchain, it could be removed from there during reorganization.  That's why one would wait for multiple confirmations (i.e. blocks mined after the block transaction was included into) to ensure transaction is permanently stored inside blockchain.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail Vladimirov! Al least theoretically there is the opportunity to store this data when running a node, similar to what could be done for BTC. However, I find this data publicly for BTC (see here, this transaction got included in the blockchain ~80 minutes after it got distributed by the nodes: https://www.blockchain.com/de/btc/tx/e87f138c9ebf5986151667719825c28458a28cc66f69fed4f1032a93b399fdf8). Any idea for ETH?

Comment: See chart titled "Confirmation Time by Gas Price" [here](https://ethgasstation.info/).